# Use JQuery to extract textual value of xml element called "Title" in IE 8

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, internet-explorer-8

I've written a search service based around Solr to index a database of objects called clips. The search service returns search results formatted using the OpenSearch atom extensions formats. Clips have various properties, ClipID and Title are the two properties relevant to my question.

I have written a very simple JavaScript program using jquery which invokes the search service asynchronously in the background and populates a table with the ClipId and Title values. The program works fine on Chrome, Safari and FF. However, on IE, it simply fails to parse the value of the Title attribute. It is as if "Title" is a reserved XML tag name and jQuery on IE simple can't find it.

Here is the extract from my JavaScript program:

```
   // Ajax call to the search service over HTTP.
   var doSearch = function(){
     var query = "Title:" + $("#searchQuery").val() + "*";

     $.ajax({
      url : "/quantel/search/select" ,
      data:{q:query},
      error:function(request,status,error){
       alert(request + "," + status + "," + error);
      },
      dataType: "text/xml",
      success:function(data,status,request){
       // Clear the data table.
       $("#searchResults").dataTable().fnClearTable();
       // Search for all clip entries in the XML document.
       $(data).find("entry").children("content").each(function(index,element) {

        var clipID= $(element).children("ClipID").text();
        var title = $(element).children("Title").text();

        // Add the clip id and title to the table.
        $("#searchResults").dataTable().fnAddData([clipID,title]);
       });    
      }
     });
   };
```

And here is a sample of search results that I am trying to parse. As you can see the Content tag contains a Title tag, yet, IE simply can't find it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <title>ProjectFolders Search</title>
 <link href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=guillaume*&amp;rows=100&amp;" />
 <link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=guillaume*&amp;rows=100&amp;" />
 <link rel="first" href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=guillaume*&amp;rows=100&amp;start=0" />
 <link rel="last" href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=guillaume*&amp;rows=100&amp;start=0" />
 <link rel="previous" href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=guillaume*&amp;rows=100&amp;start=0" />
 <link rel="next" href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=guillaume*&amp;rows=100&amp;start=0" />
 <updated>2010-11-29T14:45:53.796Z</updated>
 <author>
  <name>Quantel</name>
 </author>
 <id>urn:uuid:cd9d3362-2159-4c27-a99e-9691dd4ff707</id>
 <opensearch:totalResults>6</opensearch:totalResults>
 <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
 <opensearch:itemsPerPage>100</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
 <entry>
  <title type="html">Guillaume_clip</title>
  <updated>2010-10-25T11:10:17.000+01:00</updated>
  <id>urn:clipid:389685</id>
  <link href="http://localhost:8182/quantel/search/select?q=ClipID:389685" />
  <content type="text/xml">
   <PlaceHolder>0</PlaceHolder>
   <HasEditData>0</HasEditData>
   <id>389685</id>
   <ClipID>389685</ClipID>
   <Created>2010-10-25T11:10:17.000+01:00</Created>
   <NumVidTracks>0</NumVidTracks>
   <CloneZone>119</CloneZone>
   <MosActive>0</MosActive>
   <Template>0</Template>
   <Completed>2010-10-25T11:10:18.000+01:00</Completed>
   <Frames>0</Frames>
   <Title>Guillaume_clip</Title>
   <UnEdited>1</UnEdited>
   <ClipGUID>7e5aef9c7da44bacbfb49500710138cf</ClipGUID>
   <CloneID>389685</CloneID>
   <NumAudTracks>0</NumAudTracks>
  </content>
 </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: But the line with `"ClipID"` works? (Also, can you try `var title = element.getElementsByTagName("Title")[0];` instead?)

Comment: 'dataType' option of the $.ajax call has invalid value. It should be 'xml'. see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The line with ClipID works. As a matter of fact, attempting to retrieve all fields other than Title work. I've tried var title = element.getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].text and it works on Chrome but not on IE.

Comment: Hi @thorn, I don't think the dataType is the problem. I think I just found the answer: http://www.rachaelarnold.com/dev/archive/the-title-element-and-jquerys-text-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataType` option of the `$.ajax` call has an invalid value. It should be `xml`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

In your case with an invalid data type IE parses the content as HTML, so the `title` element is moved into the `head` element.

Also MIME-type of the response should be `text/xml`. If you need to keep some other MIME type, you can parse an XML response in the way described here: http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the title element being moved to the head element. This makes sense. However, when I set the dataType of $.ajax to be xml it does not work and I get a parse error. I am pretty sure the XML is well formed as I can read it directly from IE and it does not complain. I was initially using $.get as a shortcut for $.ajax but it did not work.

Comment: Does your server return the correct MIME type for this content (text/xml)?

Comment: The correct MIME type for this type of content is application/atom+xml

Comment: IE might not be aware of this type.

Comment: Thanks for your help @thorn I think going forward I will actual extend the search engine to produce search results in plain xml or json alongside open search format. I think this will make browser integration a bit easier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The title should be in different namespace. You can try

$(elment).find('atom\:Title').text();

On iPad , can't try it now.